# distribution as global variable

Tags: c++, random, global-variables

In my project, I am trying to use a uniform distribution as a global variable.

In one file (global.h), I write:

```
#include <random>
extern std::uniform_real_distribution<> sample;
```

Then, in another file, I want to initialize it (set the parameters) with:

```
#include "global.h"
std::uniform_real_distribution<>::param_type Params(-0.3,0.3);
sample.param(Params);
```

But I get the following error message:
 *'sample' does not name a type*

Any suggestions?

Comment: You can't call methods in global scope...

Comment: extern std::uniform_real_distribution<> sample is only declared you should initialize the variable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't just do this in global scope:

```
sample.param(Params);
```

You have to do it within some function:

```
void setupParams() {
    sample.param(std::uniform_real_distribution<>::param_type{-0.3, 0.3});
}
```

Which could be wrapped in the constructor of some other type:

```
class MyDistribution {
public:
    MyDistribution() {
        sample.param(std::uniform_real_distribution<>::param_type{-0.3, 0.3});
    }

private:
    std::uniform_real_distribution<> sample;
};
```

So that you can have:

```
// header
extern MyDistribution dist;

// the one cpp file
MyDistribution dist;
```

Also don't forget that `extern` simply declares a variable. You still have to define it - otherwise you will get a linker error on undefined reference to `sample`.

Comment: one option will be to declare it `static` in some function which returns it, so you get access whenever needed.

Comment: Thanks,! But where do I call this function? Inside the functions where I need the distribution? It is not quite clear to me how to deal with the function.

Comment: @beginneR Provided an example

Answer (score 0):

Write your code in function

```
void func()
{
    std::uniform_real_distribution<>::param_type Params(-0.3,0.3);
    sample.param(Params);
}
```